# How do I get the sales order items by the sales rep in netsuite api with PHP?

Tags: php, api, netsuite

Here is the situation, I'm trying to get the sales data based on the sales rep id.

Here is what I have tried (of course failed)

```
     $request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
     $request->baseRef->internalId = 730;
     $request->baseRef->type = 'salesRep';
     $getResponse = $service->get($request);
```

What will be the best way to the sale information based on the salesRep id?

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution....

The problem was that I have to do a multi-select field. So instead of doing what I did that is above, here is my solution:

```
    $type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
    $type->operator = 'anyOf';
    $type->searchValue = array('_salesOrder');
    $search->type = $type;

    $salesRepRef = new RecordRef();
    $salesRepRef->internalId = 730

    $params = new SearchMultiSelectField();
    $params->operator = 'anyOf';
    $params->searchValue = array($salesRepRef);
    $search->salesRep = $params;
```

That returned the information that I needed.